# HTML5 canvas: single stroke around combined regions

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

HTML5 canvas: I'm looking for a way to draw a single stroke around a combined path.

For example if I have two overlapping circles I don't want to have two overlapping circle strokes, but one single stroke around the combined region of both circles..

Any chance for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by using `globalCompositeOperation`. There are various ways you can draw the shapes them selves but here is one approach that results in this (for the two <strike>rectangle</strike> circles in the demo):

[image]

- Step 1: setup the normal canvas
- Step 2: setup an off-screen canvas

**Update** Not sure how I could miss the obvious, but you can of course just *stroke* the circles first, then punch a whole with composite mode and a fill - much faster (I guess I had images on my mind when I came up with the offset redraw).

The reason for off-screen canvas is if you have something in the background already on the main canvas. This will be deleted otherwise where we punch the hole. If nothing is there there is no problem drawing this to a single canvas - updated code:

```
/// some regions
var rect = [ [20, 20, 200, 200], [100, 100, 200,200] ],

/// ox = off-screen context
ox.strokeStyle = '#fff';
ox.lineWidth = 3 * 2; /// x2 as half will be gone when we punch hole

/// stroke outlines
for(; r = rect[i]; i++) {
    o = r[2] * 0.5;
    ox.beginPath();
    ox.arc(r[0] + o, r[1] + o, o, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ox.stroke();
}

/// punch hole with composite mode and fill
ox.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';    
for(i = 0; r = rect[i]; i++) {
    o = r[2] * 0.5;
    ox.beginPath();
    ox.arc(r[0] + o, r[1] + o, o, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ox.fill();
}

/// draw result to main canvas
/// ctx = main context, ocanvas = off-screen canvas
ctx.drawImage(ocanvas, 0, 0);
```

**[(Animated) online demo using this optimized version](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/c3VWD/)**

*I'll leave the old code as it can be used for images that can't be stroked -*

Now draw the shapes **filled** to the off-screen canvas. Draw in the color you want the outline to be in.

```
/// some regions
var rect = [ [20, 20, 200, 200], [100, 100, 200,200] ],

/// ox = off-screen canvas
ox.fillStyle = '#fff';

/// draw the array with circes
for(; r = rect[i]; i++) {
    var o = r[2] * 0.5;
    ox.beginPath(); //use this here - arcs are currently buggy
    ox.arc(r[0] + o, r[1] + o, o, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ox.fill(); //.. and here
}
```

Now draw the cached image of the shapes back to main canvas. the shapes must be drawn with a slight offset in each direction - this step will create the outline:

```
/// ctx = main context, ocanvas = off-screen canvas
ctx.drawImage(ocanvas, -1, -1);
ctx.drawImage(ocanvas, 1, -1);
ctx.drawImage(ocanvas, 1, -1);
ctx.drawImage(ocanvas, 1, 1);
ctx.drawImage(ocanvas, -1, 1);
ctx.drawImage(ocanvas, 1, 1);
ctx.drawImage(ocanvas, -1, -1);
ctx.drawImage(ocanvas, -1, 1);
```

And finally we punch a "hole" in the filled shape to make it transparent with an outline using `globalCompositeOperation` + a final draw in 0 offset position :

```
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
ctx.drawImage(ocanvas, 0, 0);
```

<kbd>**[ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/KkqsT/)**</kbd>

To make the border thicker just increase the offset when you draw back the shapes to main canvas.

Comment: For the heck of it, an animated version: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/c3VWD/

Comment: I posted a new answer with my current solution, since code formatting in comments is not that good..

Answer (score 0):

That's my current solution. Doesn't need a second canvas and is easier to achieve. It still uses the Ken's idea to use `globalCompositeOperation`:

```
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.stroke();
var prev = context.globalCompositeOperation;
context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
context.fill();
context.globalCompositeOperation = prev;
```