# Can I draw two shapes on top of each other and have a combined stroke/outline?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So far I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/gautamadude/MQuxC/1/

But obviously the stroke isn't correct, it should be around the irregular shape instead of crossing over.

Is it possible to achieve this through some globalCompositionOperator gymnastics or other means, or do I have to just draw it "step by step" instead of drawing a circle and a rect on top of each other?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var d_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = d_canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();

var circle_x = 150;
var circle_y = 150;
var radius = 50;
var corners = 10;
var width = (radius*2)/1.1
var height = 50;
var x = circle_x - width/2;
var y = circle_y - 70;

context.moveTo(x + corners, y);
context.lineTo(x + width - corners, y);
context.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + corners);
context.lineTo(x + width, y + height - corners);
context.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - corners, y + height);
context.lineTo(x + corners, y + height);
context.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - corners);
context.lineTo(x, y + corners);
context.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + corners, y);

context.arc(circle_x, circle_y, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);

context.fillStyle = "#000000";
context.fill();
context.strokeStyle = "red";
context.stroke();
context.endPath();
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 canvas: single stroke around combined regions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978473/html5-canvas-single-stroke-around-combined-regions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use Compositing to outline your combined shapes**

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/EucUZ/

[image][image]

If you want to both stroke and fill your rect+arc, just do the fill() after the stroke().

```
drawYourPath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fill();
```

If you want just the outline stroke, you can use compositing:

```
drawYourPath();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
ctx.fill();
```

This code can be slightly enhanced

- Save/Restore the context so we don’t inadvertently leave compositing ON.
- Double the lineWidth since compositing will remove half the stroke width

The revised code:

```
ctx.save();
drawYourPath();
ctx.lineWidth*=2;
ctx.stroke();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation="destination-out";
ctx.fill();
ctx.restore();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired effect with clipping :
- fill and stroke rounded rect
- fill lower circle
- then, to stroke the right part of the circle :
-- first clip the whole canvas
-- then clip out the upper rect
-- now stroke the circle.

Do this with a lineWidth of 0 since you want to define precisely your rect.

Now you can draw, it will draw everywhere but in the rect.

I approximated the upper rect to a regular rect, which is ok in this case :

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/MQuxC/3/

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var d_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = d_canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = "red";

    context.beginPath();
    var circle_x = 150;
    var circle_y = 150;
    var radius = 50;
    var corners = 10;
    var width = (radius * 2) / 1.1
    var height = 50;
    var x = circle_x - width / 2;
    var y = circle_y - 70;
    context.moveTo(x + corners, y);
    context.lineTo(x + width - corners, y);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + corners);
    context.lineTo(x + width, y + height - corners);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width - corners, y + height);
    context.lineTo(x + corners, y + height);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - corners);
    context.lineTo(x, y + corners);
    context.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + corners, y);
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(circle_x, circle_y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = "#000000";
    context.fill();

    context.save();
    // clip the whole canvas...
    clipCanvas();
    // then draw a hole with the upper rect
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    context.lineTo(x, y + height);
    context.lineTo(x + width, y + height);
    context.lineTo(x + width, y);
    context.lineTo(x, y);
    context.clip();
    // stroke the circle = everywhere except in the rect
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.arc(circle_x, circle_y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.stroke();
    context.restore();

    function clipCanvas() {
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = 0;
        context.moveTo(0, 0);
        context.lineTo(context.canvas.width, 0); // width/h should be cached if performance matters.
        context.lineTo(context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
        context.lineTo(0, context.canvas.height);
        context.lineTo(0, 0);
        context.clip();
    }

});
```